# Create field based on an existing field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch index that stores products and it's properties like size, color, material as a dynamic field:

```
"raw_properties" : {
  "dynamic" : "true",
  "properties" : {
    "Color" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : { "type" : "keyword", "ignore_above" : 256 }
      }
    },
    "Size" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : { "type" : "keyword", "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

An indexed document looks like this:

```
{
  "_index" : "development-products",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "3",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source" : {
    "raw_properties" : {
      "Size" : ["XS", "S", "XL"],
      "Color" : ["blue", "orange"]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is, that the value of `raw_properties` comes from various sources, and they differ a lot. For example, the field `Color` is called `Colour` from another source, and `blue` could be `light-blue` and so on.

So, I've implemented a normalization step in my app, that does a simple mapping like this (for simplicity, the mapping here is just a Ruby Hash, in reality the mapping is read from a database):

```
PROPERTY_MAPPING = {
  "Colour_blue" => ["Color", "blue"],
  "Color_light-blue" => ["Color", "blue"],
  "Size_46" => ["Size", "S"]
}
```

When my app indexes a product, it looks into this property mapping and normalizes the property. This keeps the cardinality of the fields low and the user isn't presented with too much properties to filter.

**The problem:** Updating those mappings is pretty slow, as I have to reindex the affected products by applying the new mapping in my app and sending the data to Elasticsearch. I'm dealing with about **3 million products** here, and new data with a new normalization comes in every day. I try to only find the products that are affected and so on, but it is still too slow.

So I was thinking if there was a way to do the normalization inside Elasticsearch? I've read about enriching data (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest-enriching-data.html) or the pipelines with processors (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest-processors.html) and had a look into Painless.

The main idea would be to only update the mapping, do an `update_by_query`, and let Elasticsearch take care of the rest.

So, I'm not sure if this is possible at all or where I should start. Any advice or hint is appreciated!

Comment: Your approach makes sense. I was going to suggest leveraging ingest pipeline and potentially the enrich processor. This is how I'm usually standardizing thousands of disparate properties coming from many different sources. It's pretty easy to set up, the only question is how to identify the documents to update once you have modified your property mapping.

Comment: @Val for the searching, I think I can use the `raw_properties` field. When the mapping updates, e.g. `Colour > Color` I can search via an exists query for every document that has `Colour` inside it's `raw_properties`. Do you have a sample how this could work with the ingest pipeline or the enrich processor?

Comment: regarding `new data with a new normalization comes in every day`, if this is new data coming in, why do you need to update existing data? My understanding is that existing data is already standardized and only new data would be impacted and need to be updated. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Val I meant new products with unmapped properties. For example, new products are imported that have properties that haven't been mapped before. When I see unkown properties, an admin manually maps this properties to existing properties or creates a new one. So after every import, there could be products that needs mapping. And once you update the mapping, you would have to reindex the products

Comment: Ok, but you only need to reindex/update new products that have just been imported, not ones that have been imported the day before and that have been properly mapped in the meantime, correct? Or do you sometimes also change existing standard fields from past products?

Comment: And process-wise, why do you import the new unmapped products directly into your index and not in a staging environment? The issue by doing so is that the field mappings in  `raw_properties` will constantly grow and potentially result in mapping explosion.

Comment: I also need to reindex old products once someone had the time to update a mapping. A staging environment wouldn't help: Once a product is imported, it should be searchable. The property mapping is a manual process to tame the chaotic properties that I get from the sources. And you're right, this will constantly grow and maybe can't be handled once it's too big. Maybe I would look for some AI then, but in the meantime, a manual mapping seems like the best option.

Comment: What I would suggest then is to stage those properties into `raw_properties` but with `enabled: false` so that they don't get indexed and don't grow the mapping unnecessarily. If a product comes in with non-standard field names and values, I don't see how it is possible to search for it until it is standardized, since the field names are not known by your queries.

Comment: Do you have any experience, how big such a mapping can get? I think it may be a few thousand unique properties, so I think that would not be a problem when I index them. So, how would you suggest could I do the mapping inside ES? Enriching sounds promising, but there are so many options to choose from, just seeking for some guidance where to start.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#mapping-limit-settings), the default sensible limit is set to 1000 fields per mapping. You can of course increase that limit, but the fact that the default is set at 1000 tells a lot. The more fields land into your mapping, the worse the performance can get. Indexing is never a problem, but search is.

Comment: As I said, `raw_properties` should have `enabled:false` in your mapping. Then whenever you detect new products with non-standards field names/values, you can update your property mapping, and then standardize your new products with the latest property mapping so that all the new products only index standard field names/values.

Comment: I see... maybe I add an additional field indexed as text, so that I could find the documents that needs a reindex when new properties are configured. I think it wouldn't be too bad if you get some false-positives, e.g. you index more products that you would need too. Maybe that's good & fast enough.

Assuming the problem finding the docs to reindex is solved, how could I use the ingest pipeline or enrich processor to apply the new standardized properties?